How can I secure a flatware holder in a drawer?
When I shove the drawer in and out the plastic knife holder slides fore and aft. (They are "fling to close" self-closing type drawer mechanism.)
I don't really like adhesives but there is no really good way to use fasteners.
Do I really just dab some silicone under there? Perhaps silicone would stain the wood?
Reasons to not drill: if I made 2 or 4 tiny holes in the plastic object, then tiny holes in the (fairly thin) drawer bottom: then use tiny nut/bolts. As night follows day, the first time my wife puts a knife in (let's say, in Slot Four) she would be yelling at me why are my knifes being scratched on some tiny metal object in the slot?
... I wouldn't really be able to get in to the minuscule areas on the ground floor BETWEEN! the angled slots
... I thought of 2 fasteners on the right against the wall of the drawer, but same issue
... I thought of four elegant little blocks four and aft of the plastic piece, but the plastic piece would just pop out eventually, plus it ruins the whole minimalist vibe, plus it gets in the way of knives in nearby slots
... i thought of drilling four (incredibly precisely placed :/ ) small holes in the drawer base, and, permanently-adding to the plastic object four pegs, but the twin problems are (a) stuff permanently added to plastic pieces, not originally molded on, always come off and (b) it takes too much precision, nobody can really post-mold modd plastic
Another problem is you want the thing to be really flat, gapless. (For example, if used double-sided foam tape, that doesn't work at all.)
On top of all that you likely really want to be able to take out to clean it and the drawer from time to time.

As a related curiosity, I had this thing made,


Which I suppose is like a hand-made wooden version of a ($2 plastic) wedge holder. Because it has heaps of guts at the bottom, and is wood, it could easily be correctly fixed to or built in to the draw.  Unfortunately it's totally useless as (I now see) the thickness of the device at the bottom has to be tiny, and I guess the reason for the "wedge" idea is that, you know, it works :) This thing is as useless as an ordinary knife holder or block.

granite counter tops are really just held in place by some sort of silicon The difference is that granite counter tops are HEAVY. So gravity helps keep them in place.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - right; so you're saying silicon probably WOULD NOT hold this in place in this case?  BTW what the heck is you buy when you need "silicon"? Is it just in a tube labelled "silicon" or ??

Am kind of looking for an answer to the headline question, perhaps by some adhesives or woodworking expert or plasticsworking expert?  (I'm useless, I only know about Clag and Superglue :/  )

@mikes I will try that again but as I may have mentioned, it's shitty as it raises it, it looks tacky you know?  TY though .. I will go see if there are "slimline" available!

Well, the usual term is actually "silicone", not "silicon". But beyond that, I'm not sure. The things I find in a quick search are "silicone sealant and adhesive" which would probably work but I have a feeling would not remove easily or cleanly (i.e., messing up the drawer) if/when you want to replace the knife holders with something else.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact precisely - that's literally what i'm asking.  If I use "the silicon stuff like granite workers use, will that (a) ever come off again and (b) mess up the wood"

I hate to add to the nitpicking, but my fingers winced seeing this "device". I'd scrap it for something safer. You're looking for an "in-drawer knife block".

@Fattie, you have rejected every answer we provided you. We cannot foresee your taste in drawer organizational decorating.  Have you tried visiting one of those kitchen supply stores?

Based on comments from the OP this has morphed into a decorating question. So I am voting to close.

Anything which is easy to separate risks separating by itself. Having said that, my go-to temporary adhesives are double-sided tape, and hot glue. Thin tapes are available, but will not conform as well to a non-smooth surface and maybe at more risk of coming loose unexpectedly. Standard hot glue is designed to be temporary; it sits on the surface of materials and can be popped free fairly easily, usually with minimal staining. Personally, I worry more about a kitchen drawer's functionality than its appearance, but one of these might do what you were looking for.

@AdamO ?  I'm surprised, do you have or have you tried an in-drawer knife block?  (I have a number, including custom made ones.). Surely you have tried one of these recently-on-the-market "wedge holders" which are incredibly better in every way?  No?  Knife blocks are garbage, they just get thrashed around.  The "wedge holder" thing is the only way to store serious knives. However, per my question, they are kind of crap in drawers since they move, unless you ego sideways, and I don't have a wide enough drawer!

If you have some interest in knife holders @AdamO I also had an interesting hand-made WOODEN "wedge holder" made by a woodworking company in Europe, I'll add a photo.  It's actually worthless because instead of the wedge concept it just has "slots", so it's as utterly useless as conventional "knife holders".  editing in a pic.

The blades are supposed to point down when they are in the block.

Removable double-sided tape holds really well in shear and won't damage your drawer. I'd use a fairly thin foam type. The foam helps handle imperfections in the flatness of your holder.
Trim it so it's hidden under the bottom panels. Use 4-6 strips running front-to-back.

I realize that you dismissed this elegant, simple, inexpensive solution in your question, but I'm disregarding your criticism. It's a freaking drawer. The answer stays for less fussy types.

Did you read your post? Another problem is you want the thing to be really flat, gapless. (For example, if used double-sided foam tape, that doesn't work at all.)

Use a drawer liner to cover the whole bottom of the drawer. You may also want to put more things in to fill the space, so they hold each other in place.
Edited: Cut the drawer liner to the size of the underside of your plastic knife holder, and glue/double-sided tape the liner to the bottom. This will give enough friction yet not visually different from what you have now.
And, please fill more stuff in! Your drawer is so empty!

Cheers Guang, a drawer liner is actually an amazing idea !!  However, it would be great to keep the minimalist look of the wood and the wedge-knife holder.
